Modelling invariants over different aggregates
I am creating a simple Meal Tracking application and want to employ Domain-Driven Design principles. I've stumbled upon a Design problem that I'm not sure how to solve. Here are the components so far:
Food (Entity):
 - name
 - nutritional data
 - List of units //Food could be measured in different Units, e.g. gr, ml, pieces

Meal (Entity):
 - name
 - List of ingredients

Ingredient (Value Object):
 - foodId
 - amount
 - unit

Meal and Food are aggregates. Ingredient belongs to the Meal aggregate, thus I have modeled the Food association as an ID (instead of an Entity Reference).
One requirement is that the unit in Ingredient needs to match one of Food's units. How do I check this invariant?

I could check it within the Meal aggregate (meal.addIngredient(food, amount, unit)), but this implies an Entity reference to a different aggregate - which should be avoided afaik.

I could create an IngredientFactory that uses a FoodRepository to fetch the Food and check the invariant. This is my preferred option right now but seems like an overkill.

I could let the application layer make sure that only valid units are provided. But now the domain layer gives away control over its invariants.


What would be the proper solution - or is the design itself flawed?

A model is a simplified view of reality. An ingredient (egg) does not know in which foods it is used. It does not make sense to model it like that. Having a unit property on Ingredients is fine, if it means how that ingredient is measured.

Why are food and meal aggregates? What is the public behavior on those? What’s the difference between these concepts, both in reality and in your model?

@RikD; I think it is pretty clear how to interpret this model. Food means type of food, ingredient means "number of units of a certain food as part of a meal". So yes, an ingredient like "3 eggs in a cake" know precisely that its is of the type "egg". Since eggs are usually measured by piece, the only unit in the entity "food" will be "piece", and any ingredient of type "egg" needs to have "piece" as unit.

@DocBrown I would give food a list of ingredients, or a list of a new concept that combines ingredient with the amount (if I or the domain expert could come up with a meaningful name for that concept). Nevertheless, a model exists for a reason and discussing the model without knowing what its supposed to do is rather pointless.

@DocBrown you got it right. however, there's one correction (and that's the whole crux): I would like to measure eggs as grams as well. this allows me to create very precise meal plans for very specific macro nutrient goals. for example if 3 eggs are 300g, I could mix them up and consume 150g today and 150g tomorrow. this is the idea behind food having different types of units. otherwise, I would get away with having only one main unit per Food and Ingredient wouldn't have to specify it.

@PhilippMurry: yes, I understood this. just measuring eggs in grams is quite unusual in typical recipes. I would have chosen a different example, but it wasn't my example.

@RikD "Food" is not a Meal - its the raw materials used to cook a meal; like egg, milk, chicken, chocolate, etc. an Ingredient binds these raw materials to a Meal by specifying an amount. not sure if you understood the model that way.

There is nothing wrong when a Meal object checks the business rule ("ingredient's unit is among food units") using a Food object, or when the Ingredient object itself does this. An Ingredient object will not store the entity reference to the Food aggregate (only the ID), hence the Food object is only used temporarily. That's not against DDD rules of modeling aggregates. Hence your approach #1 is fine.
Still, in case Food and/or Ingredient are not immutable, it may not be sufficient to validate the rules at construction time, or at the time when ingredients are added. The Food units or Ingredient units may change afterwards and become temporarily inconsistent. Hence you could also add a Validate method to Ingredient, which gets the FoodRepository as parameter and validates the rule. That's very similar to option #2. I don't consider this "overkill", but if you don't like it, you could alternatively add a Validate method to Meal and implement the validation for all its ingredients there. That would allow optimizations like querying for the Food objects of the ingredients of a Meal all at once.
Finally, in case the objects are not immutable, you have to call the validation for a meal somewhere - maybe at the beginning of some operation which uses the ingredients and expects correct units ( "Meal.cook()", or "Meal.PrintRecipe()", or maybe somewhere else in the application). That is the part for the application level you have to care for, still the core logic will stay in the Domain logic.

In short
The aggregates are by definition a unit for the purpose of changes and for maintaining invariants. But often aggregate internal invariants are not sufficient for ensuring the global consistency across all the aggregates.
The solution to this problem is to orchestrate the change of aggregates for example using domain events and/or the saga pattern. There are also lighter pragmatic alternative but it's more for very simple systems.
But there are ways to avoid the invariant, or to significantly reduce the probability of breaking the invariants.
More details
General solution
To enforce the global consistency and the contraints of business rules you need to orchestrate the changes with domain events and the saga pattern:

When creating or change the aggregate, you'd verify the constraints agains external entities.  If more than one aggregate needed to be changed in a coordinated way, you'd use a saga to be able to undo changes that would create an inconsistency.
Domain events allow to subscribe to changes of aggregates one depend on.  So meal could subscribe to changes of the food its ingredient depend on.  When receiving an event,  it would check that it's still consistent with the changes that were notified. This implies that there could be a temporal mismatch.
The saga pattern would on the top need a stepwise approach to ensure a reverting of inconsistent changes if there's no other way out.

A Simpler alternative to the subscription, at least in very simple systems, and in this particular case, would be to move the enforcement of the change constraint to the Food aggregate:

Whenever the list of units is changed, verify the ones that are removed and make sure no meal using that food in an indegrient is using this unit.

This alternative not so great from a conceptual point of view, as food would need to know about the Meal, but it is rather simple to implement and avoids temporary mismatch. A better design could be to move the verification to a business rule engine.
Units and dimensions - how to avoid the invariant in the first place
There are only three types of measures for food: weight (g, kg, lb, ...), volume (ml, l, spoon, ...) and pieces.
Within each of these dimensions, there are simple absolute conversion factors. Why bother users not to use kilograms instead of the grams and pounds that where explicitly mentionned for "sugar" ?  Wouldn't it be better to only specify the appropriate dimension and let the user use whatever compatible unit of measure that is desired?
To be even more provocative, between the dimensions there are also conversion factors applicable for each kind of food (example: 1 ml of milk is in average 1.03 g, 1 piece of egg is between 50 and 70 g so let's average to 60).
If you keep track for each food of three inter-dimension conversion factors, you no longer need to worry about the unit used in the ingredient. No more unnecessary invariant. This doesn't prevent to encourage users to use a preferred unit or dimension.

Pros: no need to enter lots of possible measures in each an every food, one less invariant to ensure.
Cons: need to find additional data for your food, and accept some possible loss of precision.

Mixing both approaches
I'd suggest to assign each food to a dimension rather than a specific list of units: it's either countable and measured in pieces (like eggs), liquid and measured accordingly by volume (like milk) or measure by weight (like sugar).
Each food would then accept all the possible units of the corresponding dimension. The invariants gets transformed: the dimension of the meal units unit corresponds shall match the dimensions used by the foods.

Pros: quantity system is much more flexible, and the dimension to be used for a food is very unlikely to change in practice, compared to your original design (i.e. it may change mainly in case of an error in the initial entry).
Cons: a little more work in the unit system


I think you forgot to mention one simple alternative for dealing with the business rule / invariant: allowing the rule to be broken temporarily (a.k.a "eventual consistency").  That avoids the need for the Saga pattern, does not require Domain events and avoids Food objects having to know about the meals.

@DocBrown This is indeed the case of the saga pattern and described in the link. i mentioned it in an earlier version but it got lost in the simplification edits.  It's still there implicitly, since the alternative solution to the saga is said toi avoid temporary mismatch, which contains the claim by contraposition ;-)

@DocBrown I edited to re-clarify and also say a word about the saga pattern principle. I leave you  the exclusivity of eventual consistency.

A tricky one.
You could solve this by introducing a new entity the FoodUnit and referencing by Id. So instead of
10 x Piece of chicken

you would have
10 x ChickenPiece
5  x ChickenKilogram

etc
This makes sense for stuff where the unit are integral to the item, ie If i have frozen sized chicken pieces which must be used in the MacChick, and i'm not allowed to cut the chickens I have in the fridge into pieces and use them instead. Of if I order 5 of the red, size 10, dresses. it's not interchangeable with 3 blue size 17 dresses etc.
But, if you are already happy with the external id for Food potentially not existing, you might be equally happy for the food existing but the unit combination to be invalid. ie The recipe calls for chicken thighs, but they don't sell them anymore. Do I want to make all such recipes impossible, or just say "can't find food unit type 'thigh' for 'chicken'"?

thanks for the suggestion! although I think it would complicate the model too much. to follow up on my first point about having Food as a parameter to meal.addIngredient(...): in DDD, is there a distinction between having a persistent reference to an Aggregate versus having a transient one (like here - only as a Method argument)? because I think this would be the easiest and cleanest solution, but I don't know how much it would break DDD's guidelines and bite me in the long run.

I dont think theres an issue with using the other aggregates when you create or perform some logic with the first one. Its expected that your top level is going to have multiple aggregates in memory at the same time. The problem is when you want to maintain the invariant to the same degree of rigour as within an aggregate. ie make it impossible to persist or instantiate an invalid object. Or force all Recipes to update when you change a food's quantity type. It would be bad to have a method on AR1 have to load AG2 in order to perform its function.

so in your questions possible solutions 1 = bad 2,3 = ok
